# how can i check whether a table exists in the database (ACCESS or SQL) in C#

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access

I found a lot of questions regarding with this question.

But is there any simple statements to accomplish this task?

for both SQL and ACCESS

Comment: yea.. all are correct. But I can't use them in access. Only in sql.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
IF (EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.tables WHERE name = 'table_name'))
BEGIN
    -- do stuff
END
```

[sys.tables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187406%28v=SQL.105%29.aspx) can also give you some information about the table object, e.g. the `is_replicated` column tells you if the table was created by replication or the `has_replication_filter` column tells you if the table has a replication filter set up

NB: this is for SQL Server

Edit: 
For Access:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as Exists from MsysObjects 
WHERE type = 1
AND name = 'MY_TABLE_NAME'
```

Comment: Google says the access equivalent is MsysObjects. See http://www.mvps.org/access/queries/qry0002.htm or http://articles.techrepublic.com.com/5100-10878_11-5047664.html

Comment: @william: Added Access variant.

Comment: Thank you, the Access query really helped me with my project.

Answer (score 2):

Note that there is no standardized way to do this in SQL, you will have to write plattform-specific code.

To my knowledge, all DBMS  have this functionality in one way or another, but it differs greatly, eg in Oracle you can query the `sys.all_tables` view.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do using OBJECT_ID.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('table1') IS NOT NULL
print 'Exists' 
else
print 'Not Exists'
```